# Use route as url in config with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, symfony-forms

I use CKEditor and want to use `uploadimage` plugin. I need to specify `uploadUrl` in config.yml. How can I put here a route instead of direct url?

```
ivory_ck_editor:
    default_config: my_config
    configs:
        my_config:
            extraPlugins: "lineutils,widget,notificationaggregator,uploadwidget,notification,uploadimage,wordcount"
            uploadUrl: '/admin/upload'
```

I know I can redefine config with form builder

```
$builder->add('field', 'ckeditor', array(
    'config' => array('uploadUrl' => ...),
));
```

But I want to do it once for every form. Which is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your form as a service, you could inject the router and use it to generate the path in your form. (This ignores the possibility of setting it in `config.yml`.)

```
services:
    app.form.type.yourformtype:
        class: AppBundle\Form\YourFormType
        arguments: [@router]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Then, in your form:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $router;

    public __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $uploadRouteName = 'app_admin_upload'; // Or whatever maps out to /app/admin, re: your original question

        ...

        $builder->add('field', 'ckeditor', array(
            'config' => array('uploadUrl' => $this->router->generate($uploadRouteName)),
        ));

        ...

    }
}
```

To truly do this once for every form you should consider extending the `ckeditor` formtype and adding your route to `uploadUrl` in the `configureOptions` method using the `OptionsResolver.`. Then update the service definition to inject the router to that class, and in place of `ckeditor` in the second argument to `add` methods, use `YourCkeditorExtendedType::class`, and you won't need to add config each time.

Comment: One small thing: if you define your form as a service, when you "create" it, you should do so by getting it from the DI container, and not with a formbuilder create method. Otherwise, you'll have to manually pass a the router to it, which would defeat a lot of the work you're doing to make this process less cumbersome.